# build-helper-maven-plugin does not add sources

Tags: maven

I'm trying to generate the objects for a wsdl schema and then use them in my project.

I can see the .java files being properly generated in the generates-sources folder but they're not seen as sources in my project.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>order-generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>orderService.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/orderService</generateDirectory>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>https://localhost/orderService_v2.1/AppOrderService?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sources>
                    <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/orderService</source>
                </sources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Try to add `<phase>generate-sources</phase>` to the execution of the jaxb2 plugin

Comment: Apparently documentation is not great for this plugin, but from [source code](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/blob/f027e3453987195049f229c05b4f97f187460170/plugin/src/main/java/org/jvnet/mjiip/v_2/XJC2Mojo.java) the default phase for this goal is indeed already `generate-sources`. What did you mean by "not seen as sources in my project"? In your IDE? from your project code? Also, could you share the build log part concerning the invocation of these two goals?